# how do i stack multiple mobs in the new minecraft updates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In the new update I think 1.8 - 1.12 (now) there is no way to stack mobs, there is passenger but if you try more than one mob they get stuck together and I am hoping there is a command out there that will stack higher and not smoosh mobs.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by stack? Like on top of each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this by giving the passenger a passenger. And that passenger another passenger. Etc etc.

So for example:

```
/summon chicken ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"chicken",Passengers:[{id:"chicken",Passengers:[{id:"chicken"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: I think this could be more detailed.

Comment: You can no longer do this because of 1.14